# Recyclerview está exibindo array json inteira ao invés do objeto

Tags: android, json, array, android-recyclerview, volley

Dentro do recyclerView tudo está sendo exibido corretamente, menos o "nome" (notifier > name)

Quando uso `String creatorName = hit.getString("notifier");` ele mostra o objeto "notifier" inteiro. Quando eu uso o `String creatorName = hit.getString("name");` nada é exibido.

Eu sou iniciante ainda no mundo do desenvolvimento, então não sei mesmo como pegar um objeto de dentro de uma array de objetos, se alguém puder me dar uma ajuda eu serei eternamente grato.

Meu endpoint me retorna o seguinte json:

```
{
"notifications":[
     { "notifier":{

 "name":"Bruno Silva"
     },
"type_text":"Te deu catch",
"avatar":"https://test.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/cae31d028e5df74_avatar.jpg",
"time_text":"14:58"
}
                ]
}
```

E Essa é minha MainActivity:

```
package com.app.contatinhos;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.app.contatinhos.adapter.ExampleAdapter;
import com.app.contatinhos.model.ExampleItem;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private String notifier;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_four);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parseJSON();
    }

    private void parseJSON() {
        String url = "https://myserver.com/api/general-data?access_token=cd7e5c9535f8167d9d47084cb5a8e6a767fdf29be5877a10532417db0c060c8517cfc5f265311178068004fef17595cd";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("notifications");


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);





                                String imageUrl = hit.getString("avatar");
                                String typeText = hit.getString("type_text");



                                String creatorName = hit.getString("notifier");

                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl, creatorName, typeText));
                            }



                            mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilise o método `getJSONObject("notifier");` para pegar o objeto interno e depois utilize o `getString("name");` para pegar o nome do objeto notifier, vide pedaço de código abaixo:

```
JSONObject notifierObject = hit.getJSONObject("notifier");
String creatorName = notifierObject.getString("name");

mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl, creatorName, typeText));
```

Qualquer dúvida, você pode consultar a documentação disponível em: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)

Comment: Eu já havia conseguido, e por incrível que pareça usei até o "notifierObject" como você. Mas muito obrigado, sei que essa resposta vai ajudar alguém no futuro que assim como eu não fazia ideia de como pegar um objeto dentro de outro. Obrigado!